# How do setup.py, setup.cfg, and pyproject.toml interact with conflicting configurations?

Tags: python, build, setuptools, setup.py, pyproject.toml

When using `setuptools`, I understand that I can use either `setup.py` with `setup.cfg`, `pyproject.toml`, or some combination of these. Many tutorials and references mention that configurations are merged from these files, but it's unclear to me exactly how this merging process works.

Given that all three of these files contain (approximately) the same information, I'm unable to find much detail on how these configuration files interact when they contain conflicting information (for instance, different package names). Many tutorials suggest using a mostly empty `setup.py` with just `setup()` when using the other configuration strategies, but what happens when I set configuration options in `setup.py` that conflict with options in `setup.cfg` or `pyproject.toml`? What happens if I set a configuration option in both `setup.cfg` and `pyproject.toml`? Is there a well-defined configuration resolution order, or is the resulting "effective" configuration unspecified?

If possible, a link to some official reference containing this information would be amazing with an answer, as I'm at a loss when it comes to finding this information in any official place. In my case, this question is `setuptools`-specific, but discussing the behavior with other build backends (if different) would be awesome as well.

Thanks in advance!